# Load file into div without removing the content

Tags: jquery, html

i'm trying to load a file into a div, with already existing content. But when i'm loading the file, the content in the div is removed. How can I prevent this? Anyone who can help me? The code is shown below.

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.type_of_connection').change(function() {

        var selected_value = $(this).val();
        $('.content').not("#" + selected_value).hide();
        $("#" + selected_value).fadeIn();

        $('.supercustomer').change(function() {
            var supercustomer_id = $(this).val();   

            $("#" + selected_value).load('show_switch.php', {supercustomer_id: supercustomer_id});
            ;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="top_content">
    <div class="top_child">
        <h3>Faktureringsuppgifter:</h3>
        <label name="firstname">Förnamn:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname">
        <label name="lastname">Efternamn:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname">
        <label name="personnmbr">Personnummer:</label>
        <input type="text" name="personnmbr">
        <label name="address">Gatuadress:</label>
        <input type="text" name="address">
        <label name="zip">Postnummer:</label>
        <input type="text" name="zip">
        <label name="city">Postort:</label>
        <input type="text" name="city">
        <label name="phone">Telefonnummer:</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone">
        <label name="customernmbr">Kundnummer</label>
        <input type="text" name="customernmbr">
    </div>

    <div class="top_child">
        <h3>Uppkoppling</h3>
        <label name="connection">Typ av uppkoppling:</label>
        <select name="type_of_connection" class="type_of_connection">
            <option value="0">Ok&auml;nt</option>
            <option value="nao_adsl">Adslkunder</option>
            <option value="nao_lan">Lankunder</option>
            <option value="ovriga_adsl">Övriga adsl</option>
            <option value="stadsnat">Stadsnät</option>
            <option value="tele">Telefoni</option>
            <option value="mobilt">Mobilt</option>
            <option value="tv">Tv</option>
         </select>
        <div class="content" id="nao_adsl">
        <h3>ADSL-uppgifter:</h3>
            ADSL-tel:<input name="adsl_tel" type="text" id="adsl_tel">
            FB-nummer:<input name="fb" type="text" id="fb">
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="nao_lan">
        <?php
            include("sok.nao_lan2.php");
        ?>
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="ovriga_adsl">
            adsl
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="stadsnat">
        <label name="stadsnat">Stadsnät</label>
        <select name="stadsnat" class="stadsnat_options">
        <?php
        while($row=$link->get_object("SELECT net_lev_id, namn FROM stadsnat"))
        {
        ?>
            <option value="<?= $row->net_lev_id ?>"><?= $row->namn ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="top_child">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom_content">
</div>
```

Comment: make 2 div inside that div. in one load content through jquery  on other old content remain same. OR use Append https://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `.load()` overwrites the old content available in the current div where you want to load your content dynamically from other page. To overcome this issue instead of using `.load()` you can make use of `$.get()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selected_value = ''; // <-----make a global var here
    $('.type_of_connection').change(function() {
        selected_value = $(this).val(); // <------update the value here
        $('.content').not("#" + selected_value).hide();
        $("#" + selected_value).fadeIn();
    });

    $('.supercustomer').change(function() {
      var supercustomer_id = $(this).val();
      $.get('show_switch.php', {supercustomer_id: supercustomer_id}, function(html){
          $("#" + selected_value).append(html); //<---append the html here.
      }, "html");
    });
});
```